# Calls to load content are HTTPS not HTTP

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, https

I am deploying Backstage on Azure Kubernetes Service. I am running into an issue where my application is attempting to load the backend modules using HTTPS. The start of the request chain is HTTP. When I run on localhost HTTP is used to make the calls. How do I force my application to use HTTP for these calls.

[image]

The error seen in the console is "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

Update:

It is worth adding that when using portforwarding outside of NGINX ingress controller from the same container that the application makes HTTP calls to the modules and loads successfully.

Comment: Have you consulted the "Backstage" docs on this issue? That is, to enable a dev setting for http-only or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had a look but couldn't see anything referencing forcing HTTP requests for modules.

Comment: I think you need to add a cert to localhost so that you can https locally

Comment: So with localhost the calls are made with HTTP. When I deploy on a managed service with SSL offloading managed for me it uses HTTPS. The app can distinguish which call to make for localhost vs when HTTPS is on unless it is running using HTTP outside of local host as in the case with the NGINX Ingress Controller. I'd rather not have to add certificates and SSL offloading to NGINX in order to allow HTTPS calls, i'd rather just ensure the modules are called with HTTP as they are when running on local host including when port forwarding.